# My HTML Div Element disappears immediately when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am fetching HTML elements via AJAX and dynamically adding to a DIV element. The problem is that sometimes the DIV is loaded correctly, but sometimes it goes blank and show nothing on the DIV element even the data is logging correctly in the browser but not showing up. I am attaching links to the screenshots of the problem for better understanding.

[Page loaded for first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHSym.png)

[Page refreshed several times and data appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeBrg.png)

[Data disappears again when page is refreshed but AJAX is fetching the html code correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEc9A.png)

```js
//////fetch table from database 
var getTable = function (id, value, tableId, context){

   $.ajax({
    url:'getJSON.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:id+"="+value,
    success:function(data){
     
    
    console.log(data);
    
    ///////////////table/////////////
     
    if(data.length>0)
    {
       var table = $('#'+tableId).
          dataTable({
           "pageLength": 5,
           "lengthChange": false
          });
       var row,cell;
     var count = Object.keys(data[0]).length;
     

      for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
     
        if(context.toLowerCase()==="classenroll")
        {
         table.fnAddData([
                                    data[i].CODE,
         data[i].NAME
        ]); 

     }

     if (context.toLowerCase()==="showmodifyassign") {

      table.fnAddData([
      
           data[i].TITLE,
     
        data[i].DESCRIPTION,

        data[i].DEADLINE,

        data[i].NAME,
       
        "<a href=\"#\">Edit</a>"
       
      ]);
      
      
     }


     if (context.toLowerCase()==="submittedassignments") {

      table.fnAddData([
       
       data[i].STUDENT_ID,
       
       data[i].FULL_NAME,
       
       data[i].CLASS_NAME,

       data[i].TITLE,

       data[i].DEADLINE,

       data[i].SUBMISSION_DATE,

       "<a href = "+data[i].FILENAME+">"+"Download Now"+"</a>"
      ]);

     }

     if (context.toLowerCase()==="showdueassignments") {

      table.fnAddData([

       data[i].TNAME,

       data[i].TITLE,

       data[i].POSTINGDATE,

       data[i].DEADLINE,

       "<a target=\"_blank\" href = \"submit.php\">Submit</a>"
      ]);
      
     }

     if (context.toLowerCase()==="modifyclass") {


      table.fnAddData([

       data[i].CODE,

       data[i].NAME,

       data[i].DESCRIPTION,

       "<a href = \"#\">Edit</a>"
      ]);
      
     }

     
    
   }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  }
 }
});
 


  }


///code for the dynamic navbar

$("#wb_element_section_teacher").ready(function(e){
    
    getForm("homeTeacher");
    getTable($("#hTeacherTitle").val(),$("#hTeacherId").val(),"newAssignTable","submittedAssignments");
  topMargin(0);
 

 });
 
 $('body').on('click', '#teacherHome', function(){
         
         getForm("homeTeacher");             
        getTable($("#hTeacherTitle").val(),$("#hTeacherId").val(),"newAssignTable","submittedAssignments");
            tempHeight=650;
      $("#wb_element_section_teacher").css('height',tempHeight+'px');
      topMargin(tempHeight-divHeight);
       return false;
    });

    
    $('body').on('click', '#createAssign', function(){
      
      getForm("createAssign");
       tempHeight=650;
      $("#wb_element_section_teacher").css('height',tempHeight+'px');
      topMargin(tempHeight-divHeight);
     return false;
    });
    

    $('body').on('click', '#modifyAssign', function(){
     
      getForm("modifyAssign");
      tempHeight=950;
      getTable("showMod","somevalue","modAssign","showmodifyassign");
      $("#wb_element_section_teacher").css('height',tempHeight+'px');
      topMargin(tempHeight-divHeight);
     return false;
    });

     
     $('body').on('click', '#createClass', function(){
      getForm("createClass");
      tempHeight=650;
      $("#wb_element_section_teacher").css('height',tempHeight+'px');
      topMargin(tempHeight-divHeight);
     return false;
    });
     

     $('body').on('click', '#modifyClass', function(){
     getForm("modifyClass");
     getTable("modClass","somevalue","modClass","modifyclass");
     tempHeight=1000;
     $("#wb_element_section_teacher").css('height',tempHeight+'px');
     topMargin(tempHeight-divHeight); 
    return false;
    });

$("#wb_element_section_teacher").ready(function(){
    
    getForm("homeStudent");
    getTable("due","somevalue","dueAssignments","showdueassignments"); 
 topMargin(0);

});
}  

$('body').on('click', '#homeStudent', function(){
        
        getForm("homeStudent");   
        getTable("due","somevalue","dueAssignments","showdueassignments");          
        tempHeight=650;
  $("#wb_element_section_teacher").css('height',tempHeight+'px');
  topMargin(tempHeight-divHeight);
   return false;
});


$('body').on('click', '#enrollClasses', function(){
  
  getForm("enrollClasses");
   tempHeight=650;
  $("#wb_element_section_teacher").css('height',tempHeight+'px');
  topMargin(tempHeight-divHeight);
 return false;
});


  $('body').on('click', '#viewEnrolled', function(){
  getForm("viewEnrolled");
  getTable($("#hStudentTitle").val(),$("#hStudentId").val(),"enrolledClassesTable","classEnroll");
  tempHeight=650;
  $("#wb_element_section_teacher").css('height',tempHeight+'px');
  topMargin(tempHeight-divHeight);
 return false;
});

$('body').on('click', '#viewSent', function(){
 
  getForm("viewSent");
  getTable("sent","somevalue","sentAssignments","showsentassignments");
  tempHeight=950;
  $("#wb_element_section_teacher").css('height',tempHeight+'px');
  topMargin(tempHeight-divHeight);
 return false;
});

   

   ///////////

////JS to fetch the Elements (HTML)
getForm = function (userType){

   $.ajax({

    url: "forms.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:"type="+userType,
    success:function(data){
     console.log(data);
     $("#wb_element_section_teacher").html(data);
     return true;
    }

   });

  }
```

```html
<!--
In Javascript code:

hTeacherTitle.val() = "TEACHER_ID";
hTeacherId.val()=(Integer value) ID of the teacher returned from the Database;

-->




<!-- Code that is fetched when page loads-->
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navItems" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> </button>
</div>
<div id="navigation" class="col-md-12 ">

<ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-default collapse navbar-collapse nav-justified" id="navItems" >

    <li id="teacherHome"><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Home</a></li>
    <li id="createAssign"><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Create Assignment</a></li>
     <li id="modifyAssign"><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Modify Assignments</a></li>
     <li id="createClass"><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Create Class</a></li>
        <li id="modifyClass"><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Modify Class</a></li>
     

</ul>

</div>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:10%;"> <center><h3>New Assignments</h3></center>
</div>
<div id="newAssign">
 <table id="newAssignTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
 
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Student\'s ID</th>
      <th>Student\'s Name</th>
      <th>Class Name</th>
      <th>Assignment Title</th>
      <th>Due Date</th>
      <th>Submission Date</th>
      <th>Download</th>
  </tr> 
    </thead>
   
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
 
 </table>



</div>
```

Comment: Put some code here or jsfiddle's url, so anyone can inspect it.

Comment: please add some code else we can just guess it

Comment: [comment](https://icanhazcode.com/img/showSomeCode.png)

Comment: Added the code in the post
Please check.

Comment: Only 'Home' in the navbar will work because I have provided html code for home page only

only home page creates the problem. Else when the page is loaded every tab in the navbar works fine

Comment: Is the ajax response successful every time?  It looks like you only have a success callback.  Try adding a fail as well.  Or an always.  See what you get back.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load this HTML via Ajax when the DOM is ready? Maybe try using `$(document).ready()` rather than `$("#wb_element_section_teacher").ready()`.

Comment: I've tried this one as well but still issue remains the same. The div shows and hides spontaneously, but sometimes starts working.

Comment: Hmm, ok, well just so you know `$("#wb_element_section_teacher").ready()` is not really valid. You're checking if the DOM is ready, not a specific element.

Comment: Maybe check if the response from the server is being cached? Is the Ajax call actually being made each time?

Comment: Actually "#wb_element_section_teacher" is the id of the div element which is always available(The grey area in the screenshot) i.e only that data is loaded in this div element which is being called by AJAX. And yes the AJAX call is made successfully because after every AJAX call I am logging the data in the browser and data called by AJAX is always shown in the log when the page is loaded.